# PHP: Check validity of SQL before process it to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any class or library to php, for this task?

Thanks ;)

Comment: This is not a bad question, but some more background and detail would be helpful. Do you want to only test drive the query in general, or do you want to protect against SQL injection...? What SQL wrapper are you using, mysql, mysqli, PDO?

Comment: I guess not, since it isn't quite trivial to parse SQL, given all existing dialects of the language. Why would you want something like this? What's wrong with sending the query to MySQL and catch any errors that occur? :-)

Comment: I'm working of sql statement constructor. I'm a bit new to this, so there could be bugs and i need some kind of parser for sql validity after my sql assembler have finished building statement.

Comment: Well i guess i'll have to do it then via try catch :S. Ok thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a **local** mySQL database with **mock tables** to have statement executed there first. This will take less resources than the real request and you can then check for errors. You could write a thin wrapper for that.

Comment: Yea guess i'll do it that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if query executes without errors you can call it within transaction and rollback in the end.

Comment: I don't want to process it at all if it's invalid. There should be some parser for this task.

Comment: @Beck Why would your SQL be invalid?

Comment: @Beck - there is some parser for this task. It's built into MySQL, and results in an error. Editing your question and including more information on *why* you want to do this, what you're trying to avoid, etc, would be quite useful.

Comment: I want t avoid mysql eating resources from invalid sql statements. Guess it's not so costly after all. Unwanted requests to mysql afterall. :)

Comment: It's probably more costly for you to replicate MySQL's ability to detect query errors than it is for MySQL to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can prepare the sql statement first using **prepare()** function. If it return false, then there are errors. Otherwise, you are good to go.

Good luck.

Comment: I see this answer has 1 downvote, but what's actually _wrong_ with relying on `prepare`?